# C# conditional statements in menuitem in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-statements, menuitem

My project has been changed to C#, from VB. I do want the conditional to be done in the menuitem.  I realize there may be other ways of doing it, however, I want it to be done in the menuitem.

I need to do a conditional in the menuitem so that menu links show up based on user role (admin,coordinator, instructor,learner).

Below is the menu code. Text in brackets shows the conditions.

```
<asp:Menu ID="MyMenu" runat="server" DynamichorizonalOffset="2"
          ForeColor="#000E8F" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Width="50%" CssClass="verticalmenu" 
          Font-Size="11pt" OnMenuItemClick="MyMenu_MenuItemClick">
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="IE8Fix" verticalPadding="2px" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="horizonalmenu" VerticalPadding="5px" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle verticalPadding="2px" ItemSpacing="2px" 
                         CssClass="horizonalmenu" />
    <StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="#7D00B6" />
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Accounts/Menu.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Search/Register for Classes" Value="Search/Register for Classes" NavigateUrl="~/Registration/SearchCourses.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Transcript [For Learner Only]" Value="Transcript"  NavigateUrl="~/InserviceHistory/InserviceTranscript.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Request for In-Service Credit [For Learner Only]" Value="My Menu" NavigateUrl="~/InserviceCredit/IndividualRequest/InstructionalIndividualCreditRequest.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Users [Admin, Coord, Instr]" Value="My Menu">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Administrator [Admin only]" Value="My Menu">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Add" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Coordinators [Admin and Coord only]" Value="My Menu">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Add" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

I have found two ways of doing conditionals yet no clue how to incorporate them, these are the examples I found (not coded for my menu example):

```
    ----Example 1 -----
<%  Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim message As String 

    If count = 0 Then
        message = "There are no items." 
    ElseIf count = 1 Then
        message = "There is 1 item." 
    Else
        message = "There are " & count & " items." 
    End If
%>

    ----Example 2 ------

<%
if(1==1)
{%>

html code

<% } 
else 
{
%>
NOt 1

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally do not like mixing C# code in mark up. It is really fragile.

Instead, you can create entire menu from code-behind in your scenario.

### ASPX

```
<asp:Menu ID="MyMenu" runat="server" DynamichorizonalOffset="2"
    ForeColor="#000E8F" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Width="50%" CssClass="verticalmenu"
    Font-Size="11pt" OnMenuItemClick="MyMenu_MenuItemClick">
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="IE8Fix" VerticalPadding="2px" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="horizonalmenu" VerticalPadding="5px" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle VerticalPadding="2px" ItemSpacing="2px"
        CssClass="horizonalmenu" />
    <StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="#7D00B6" />
</asp:Menu>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateMenu();
    }
}

private void PopulateMenu()
{
    MyMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
    {
        Text = "Home",
        Value = "Home",
        NavigateUrl = "~/Accounts/Menu.aspx"
    });


    MyMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
    {
        Text = "Search/Register for Classes",
        Value = "Search/Register for Classes",
        NavigateUrl = "~/Registration/SearchCourses.aspx"
    });


    if (User.IsInRole("Learner"))
    {
        MyMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Transcript",
            Value = "Transcript",
            NavigateUrl = "~/InserviceHistory/InserviceTranscript.aspx"
        });
        MyMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Request for In-Service Credit",
            Value = "Request for In-Service Credit",
            NavigateUrl = "~//InserviceCredit/IndividualRequest/InstructionalIndividualCreditRequest.aspx"
        });
    }

    if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Coord") || User.IsInRole("Instr"))
    {
        var usersMenuItem = new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Users",
            Value = "Users",
            NavigateUrl = "~/Accounts/Users.aspx"
        };

        usersMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Add",
            Value = "Add",
            NavigateUrl = ""
        });
        usersMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Edit",
            Value = "Edit",
            NavigateUrl = ""
        });
        usersMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Delete",
            Value = "Delete",
            NavigateUrl = ""
        });

        MyMenu.Items.Add(usersMenuItem);
    }

    if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Coord"))
    {
        var coordinatorsMenuItem = new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Coordinators",
            Value = "Coordinators",
            NavigateUrl = "~/Accounts/Users.aspx"
        };

        coordinatorsMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Add",
            Value = "Add",
            NavigateUrl = ""
        });
        coordinatorsMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Edit",
            Value = "Edit",
            NavigateUrl = ""
        });
        coordinatorsMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Delete",
            Value = "Delete",
            NavigateUrl = ""
        });

        MyMenu.Items.Add(coordinatorsMenuItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is looking like a good answer.  How does the .aspx page know to call the code behind page?  I'm new to this.  I called my code behind page "mycodebehind.cs".  Also where is the "IsInRole" variable coming from/ how does it get read.  My variables will be based on the roleid which will be in a session variable, i.e. Admin = 1, Coordinator = 2, etc. For testing purposes because the login is not set up yet, I'll add a query string to my URL i.e.  menu.aspx?roleid=1.

Comment: IsInRole is from **IPrincipal**. You can safely replace it with your original code - `Admin = 1, Coordinator = 2, etc`.  `How does the .aspx page know to call the code behind page?` When a page is requested, the ASP.NET runtime fires the Load event, which in turn calls the Page_Load method on BasePage. [Read More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649415.aspx) `I'll add a query string to my URL i.e. menu.aspx?roleid=1`. If it is your homework question, it is fine. Otherwise, it exposes a big security hole.

Comment: Yes, the URL query string is just for testing and will not be in the final product. 
With my example would i change 'if (User.IsInRole("Admin")' to 'if (User.IsInRole("1")' and is user.IsInRole then my variable i.e. ?user.IsInRole=1.

Comment: As long as  URL query string is for testing, you should be ok. Look at Figure 5 of this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649415.aspx) regarding how ASP.Net works. If you are new to ASP.Net, I won't bother reading how ASP.Net works for now. It is very advanced topic.

Comment: Yes, the URL query string is just for testing and will not be in the final product. With my example would i change 'if (User.IsInRole("Admin")' to 'if (User.IsInRole("1")' and is user.IsInRole then my variable i.e. ?user.IsInRole=1.

Comment: If url is `menu.aspx?roleid=1`, you need `string roleId = Request.QueryString["roleid"]; if (roleId == "1" || roleId == "2") { .... }`

Comment: Very close.  Got this error:
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Source Error:


Line 5:  <script runat="server">
Line 6:  
Line 7:      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Line 8:  
Line 9:      End Sub

Comment: Please create a separate question with code, since it is quite different from the original question.

Comment: Submitted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288799/compiler-error-message-cs1002-expected

Answer (score 0):

In your Load event for the page, check the type of user the current one is.

Then use this code to find the necessary menu items and remove them

```
MenuItem menuItem = MyMenu.FindItem("Users"); 
MyMenu.Items.Remove(menuItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the code behind. If you have a master page than that would be appropriate place to do it. If the user is not an admin user, you can remove the admin menu item with something like:

```
NavigationMenu.Items.RemoveAt(indexOfAdminMenuItem)
```

You may also try your way:

```
<asp:Menu ID="MyMenu" runat="server" DynamichorizonalOffset="2" ForeColor="#000E8F" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Width="50%" CssClass="verticalmenu" Font-Size="11pt" OnMenuItemClick="MyMenu_MenuItemClick">
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="IE8Fix" verticalPadding="2px" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="horizonalmenu" VerticalPadding="5px" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle verticalPadding="2px" ItemSpacing="2px" CssClass="horizonalmenu" />
    <StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="#7D00B6" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Accounts/Menu.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Search/Register for Classes" Value="Search/Register for Classes" NavigateUrl="~/Registration/SearchCourses.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Transcript [For Learner Only]" Value="Transcript"  NavigateUrl="~/InserviceHistory/InserviceTranscript.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Request for In-Service Credit [For Learner Only]" Value="My Menu" NavigateUrl="~/InserviceCredit/IndividualRequest/InstructionalIndividualCreditRequest.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Users [Admin, Coord, Instr]" Value="My Menu">
        <% 
        if (userIsAdministrator)
        {
        %>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Administrator [Admin only]" Value="My Menu">
        <%
        }
        %>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Add" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Coordinators [Admin and Coord only]" Value="My Menu">
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Add" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```