# Compiler error message CS1002: ; expected

Tags: compiler-errors

I'm getting the following error:

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Source Error:

Line 5:  
Line 6:
Line 7:      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Line 8:
Line 9:      End Sub

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" Codebehind="SimplePage.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub MyMenu_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As MenuEventArgs)

    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: If you look at the top of the source page it says `Master Language="C#"`, yet what follows looks a lot more like VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix C# and VB code inside a single page.

You can use free [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert VB to C#.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void MyMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
}
```